# Arglist differs from frame address

Tags: linux, gdb

My program failed with segfault attempting to write "1" to a string.

```
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0xb6b3c040:
 eip = 0xb7877cdf; saved eip 0xb7858eae
 called by frame at 0xb6b3cc50
 Arglist at 0x91a1649, args: 
 Locals at 0x91a1649, Previous frame's sp is 0xb6b3c040
 Saved registers:
  ebx at 0xb6b3c02c, ebp at 0xb6b3c038, esi at 0xb6b3c030, edi at 0xb6b3c034, eip at 0xb6b3c03c
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb7877cdf in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0xb7858eae in vfprintf () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0xb787d91b in vsnprintf () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0x08ea7d7e in __gnu_cxx::__to_xstring<std::string, char> (__convf=0x85a2a50 <vsnprintf@plt>, __n=16, __fmt=0x91a1649 "%u") at /usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/string_conversions.h:95
#4  0x08ea6452 in std::to_string (__val=1) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2871
...
```

I noticed that according to gdb, Arglist is not in stack. How it could happen? As far as I know, there is one calling convention in *nix: arguments are pushed to stack, caller clears stack frame. I went up and down through backtrace and everywhere else arglist was in stack.

Answer (score 0):

You could be crashing in an assembly language routine that does not follow standard calling conventions and/or have symbolic information available.

Likely, the core issue is higher up than frame 0 anyway.

Comment: thank you. I've built my application with gcc 4.6.3 and issue disappeared. I guess application compiled with 4.7.3 is not binary compatible with libc compiled with 4.6.3.